# Unable to set environment variable for ctypes (c library for python)

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ctypes

I need some third-party c library to be imported into a low-level module. I'm following [these instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html). It says that find_library() should help me find such a lib, excluding any lib prefix and .so suffix.

```
#next 2 lines just to test
test =find_library('spcm_linux')
print(test)
#this line below is the actual code
spcmDll = cdll.LoadLibrary("libspcm_linux.so")
```

Returns:

```
None
OSError: spcm_linux.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My library lives at:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspcm_linux.so
```

Reading about find_library() from the docs, it tells me that I can set an environment variable to add an environement variable (LD_LIBRARY_PATH). So in /etc/environement I have:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:"
PYTHONPATH="/home/fv/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

I restart, try and it still doesn't work (same error message).

Any other way to "find" my library? Could put it in my program.py directory directly & import it some other way?

EDIT:

However, it does find `libgomp.so.1`, which is in the exact same folder as the library I'm trying to load. If that helps...

Comment: In your snippets, in some rows the 1st *char* is missing. Is that a typo? Did you try with the full path?

Comment: Yeah that part wasn't actually linked to the real issue and more confusing than helpful. Removed it. I was just trying to see if/why my environment variable wasn't being effective. Though as explained below the real issue was rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the root of the issue was rights.

Rights to the `libspcm_linux.so` lib weren't set properly and thus the script had no access rights to it.

However, the error that popped up was still about `No such file or directory`. I presume this is because it's a C library, which ctypes tried to load. It couldn't load it (because it didn't have the rights to it) however apparently it didn't see it fit to propagate the error (or couldn't because of some technicalities of how C code is loaded, perhaps).

Therefore from it's point of view, it couldn't load the requested library, and told me so - "No such file or..." even if this hide the real cause of the problem.